# How to protect my jar resource from extraction?

Tags: java, image, resources, audio, executable-jar

I want distribute my *.jar file. I mean my application to be use but i don't want user or anybody extract my resource(sound, pic, and others).

How to protect it?

thx

Comment: And how do you stop them from taking a screenshot/recording the audio/recording the screen?

Comment: You don't want **anybody** to access your sounds and pics, not even your own program?

Comment: @cularis: At least I've tried to protect it.
@Kerrek SB: Hehehe... sorry... sorry... i mean from extraction

Comment: @Kenjiro it's pretty useless protection, if I can just get the picture by pressing PRINT or get the audio by using standard Windows tools

Comment: This is so "kiasu". But if really needed, you should go with emboss answer.

Comment: What do you want to protect them from? What kind of damage are you trying to avoid? (These aren't rhetorical questions, I genuinely think it's important to know this first.)

Comment: @Kenjiro: I was trying to make a point: If your program can access the data, and your program runs on a machine that isn't under your control, then the data cannot be protected, as it will eventually end up in the memory of that machine in order for the program to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invent a [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) mechanism and once they crack it, sue them to death.

No, honestly, what you are trying to achieve is really, really complicated - if not impossible. You would need to encrypt the resources in a way that the key to the encryption mechanism would not be contained within the jar itself (as in hardcoding it in your code - hackers love this).

So you would need your application to open some online connection to a server under your control that would need to be online all the time - and your users would hate you for doing that because of all the trouble this generates (just follow online discussions about recent PC games)... is it really worth it?

Comment: Creating that online connection would only make it a bit harder, but I would still be able to place one of my classes on the bootstrap classpath of your application and get the resources that way.

Comment: @Kaj: True that. Yes my intention was just to point out that what he looks for is the perfect DRM scheme (not just him actually), but I didn't intend to invent it here :) For images there are screenshot, for sound there is redirecting /dev/audio etc. etc. Someone clever will always find a way to "steal" copyrighted things.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible to do in Java or any language. If something can be used by your program, it can be taken. You can make it a bit more difficult for people, but at the end of the day if they want to steal graphics / sounds they can.

You'd be much better off putting your effort into making graphics and sounds etc which people like and are user-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.bfa-it.com/?lang=en&id=products/jarprotector) website introduces a `JAR` protection tool and a protected `JAR` launcher. The tools work with `Java 8` but not with e.g. `Java 11`. The ideas described in their [user manual](http://www.bfa-it.com/dld/UserManual.pdf) talks about a `ClassLoader` encryption method. The provided tools only come as a trial version though but I managed to successfully protect and launch a simple `JAR`.

`secret.txt`:

```
My secret
```

`Main.java`:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;

import static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.lookup;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception
    {
        final byte[] resourceBytes = getResource("secret.txt");
        System.out.println("Secret: " + new String(resourceBytes, UTF_8).trim());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")
    private static byte[] getResource(String filePath) throws Exception
    {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = lookup();
        Class<?> currentClass = lookup.lookupClass();
        try (InputStream inputStream = currentClass.getResourceAsStream("/" + filePath))
        {
            return toByteArray(inputStream);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[16384];

        while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1)
        {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }

        return buffer.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

`JarProtector`:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" -jar JarProtector.jar JarProtectorTest.jar

JarProtectorTrial started...
[1] protecting JarProtectorTest.jar
[1] file protected: JarProtectorTest.car
JarProtectorTrial successfully ended.
```

`JarStarter`:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" -cp JarStarter.jar;JarProtectorTest.car com.bfa.JarStarter Main
Secret: My secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Our Flash and Java Antidecompilers use a keyless encryption, i.e. don't use hardcoding for encryption key. To make sure that it is sufficient to use any decompiler. Yes, I understand that standard EULA doesn't allow it, but we give such permission by individual request at
http://www.bisguard.com/contacts.html
Goog luck